# Loss of texture detail in XNA (Banding 16 bit issue) 

Tags: xna, textures, windows-phone-7

I'm loading in a background texture for my game, it's not vert detailed, it's just there too add some variance. The problem is that there looks like a large reduction in detail. I've included images below so you can see what I'm talking about. What would cause this to happen and how can I get my detail back?

More info:
 Verticies are `VertexPositionTexture`
 Load method `Texture2D.FromStream`
 Effect `BasicEffect`

Also the project is a Silverlight/XNA mix

Source Image:
[image: Source image]

Image from game:
[image: Image from game]

Note: the images don't match up completely but you should get the idea.

Comment: Related Link: http://nullcandy.com/colour-bit-depth-in-windows-phone-apps/

Comment: Related Link: http://adtsai.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/high-quality-dithering-for-windows.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your texture is a 32 bit texture. Somewhere between loading it and displaying it, it is getting downsampled to 16-bits (or some other low bit-depth). The loss of precision gets rid of the smooth gradients and gives you bands of colour like that.

None of the things you have mentioned (loading it with `LoadStream`, drawing it with `BasicEffect` with that vertex format) will reduce precision like that.

My bet is that you're rendering to a 16-bit backbuffer. I can get a similar result by setting:

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Bgr565;
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
```

You can verify your *actual* backbuffer format (note that what you specify to `GraphicsDeviceManager` is just a preference) by checking:

```
GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat
```

It's also possible you're using a low-precision render target somewhere.

Comment: Yeah `DisplayMode.Format` is saying Bgr565 would you recommend changing it or using a 16-bit texture (assuming I can do that and it would look alright)? This is also an XNA/Silverlight project so I'm not sure if the `SharedGraphicsDevice` would like it..

Comment: Also it's a WP7 Game

Comment: I'm not up to speed with the surface limitations of WP7. If you can do a 32-bit backbuffer, that is easier. But 16-bit might have some performance benefits (less memory, more compact data). Either way, you should probably keep your textures and backbuffer in the same format. If you must have a 16-bit texture, look into *dithering* to fake the gradient at a lower bit-depth.

Comment: Yeah, I think certain devices only have 16-bit screens so I'll look into changing the texture.

Answer (score 3):

By default, in Windows Phone 7 all apps use 16 bits per pixel graphic mode. To switch it to 32 bits, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313783/126995. This is only available since WP 7.1 Mango, but since every WP7 device can be upgraded to WP 7.1, it's no big deal.

Comment: Sorry but switching to 32 bit has it's own problems, firstly there are WP7 devices that only support 16 bit so you'd still get banding. Second there is a performance penalty for doubling the format size. That's important to me because the more I do the less time I can do it for.. these are mobile devices after all.

Comment: Lavinski, could you please tell me what models don't support 32 bits? Or where you get that information? I'm currently developing an app (almost finished), and our designer created a UI that needs full-color display to look good :-(

Comment: I was unable to tell if any devices actually don't support the Color format however the hardware spec only specifies a 16-bit LCD at minimum.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway. I think we'll go live anyway, and listen to the user's feedback :-) OTOH, Wikipedia's article "Windows Phone version history" says "32 bit color support for Silverlight applications with hardware dithering", unfortunately I was unable to google any evidence for/against that..